# receiving SIGABRT from sigtimedwait function

Tags: linux, multithreading, debian, signals

I am having crash at sigtimedwait () which happened once running th block of code stated below in thread function that runs infinite amount of time.using sigtimedwait in my application running on debian 9.3 to look for SIGUSR1 signal and this is how I am using it.

```
my_fun()
{
sigset_t set;
struct timespec tm;
siginfo_t info;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
int s  = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
if (0 != s)
{
    raise(SIGABRT);
}

tm.tv_sec = 1;
tm.tv_nsec = 0;

for (;;){
if (SIGUSR1 == sigtimedwait(&set, &info, &tm)) --> Line 1077
{
}
} //end of for(infinite loop)
}
<My_filename.cpp>
```

my application is crashing at line#1077 and backtrace looks like below:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/local/bin/nelrtuapp_lan'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fe781b32d9c in __GI___sigtimedwait (set=<optimized out>,   
info=0x7ffe52a6c240, timeout=0x7ffe52a6c2c0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux                   
/sigtimedwait.c:54
54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigtimedwait.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fe782d74740 (LWP 7096))]

(gdb) bt
 #0  0x00007fe781b32d9c in __GI___sigtimedwait (set=<optimized out>,     
 info=0x7ffe52a6c240, timeout=0x7ffe52a6c2c0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  
 /sigtimedwait.c:54
 #1  0x0000555d6d53d659 in my_fun() at My_filename.cpp:1077
```

I am trying to search the source code to know more on __GI___sigtimedwait function of sigtimedwait.c , no luck in finding the the file which has the same function and would expect SIGABRT raising. I often get into following file all over GITHUB , code.woboq.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10496366/

any pointers or leads on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A process killed by SIGABRT would almost certainly have a `raise` or `kill` call near the top of the stack, and often a call to `abort` a frame or two away. But those aren't in your backtrace. gdb may have guessed the wrong thread to use as the current thread. Can you switch to the other threads and show us a backtrace that includes raise or kill?

Comment: Alternatively, can you run `thread apply all bt` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you initialize `struct timespec tm;`, recompile and run it again.

Comment: apologies, i missed copying here.